# Which gloves to avoid getting hurt by thorns

Tags: gloves

When you manipulate weed and stuff you can easily get hurt by thorns. Is there a type of garden gloves to avoid and a type to favor for reliable protection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can handle some loss of dexterity, leather welding gloves are surprisingly affordable for a long, heavy glove. The problem with "good dexterity" (thinner, tight) gloves is that serious thorns go through them (through they will protect against some of the smaller ones.)

For a lot of the nastier stuff I cut into small-ish parts with long handled pruners, and use the pruners as tweezers, rather than trying to handle it at all directly.

Answer (score 3):

They make special gardening gloves for gardeners that are marketed as "rose gloves". They have a long cuff to protect your forearms and are puncture resistant. Never used any but noticed some had good reviews when I was recently looking for other gloves.